# JSONWriter add a new Line

Tags: java, json, filewriter

I want to write several JSON Objects into a txt-file. For a better view I want that each object is in a different line and there is my problem: I don't know how to add a new line or seperate these objects.
Here is my code:

```
       JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder(); 
       builder.add("Item", item); 
       builder.add("Choice 1", idchoice1); 
       builder.add("Choice 2", idchoice2);
       builder.add("Choice 3", idchoice3);
       JsonObject jo = builder.build();
       try { 
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("SelectedChoice.txt", true); 
            JsonWriter jsonWriter = Json.createWriter(fw); 
            jsonWriter.writeObject(jo);
            jsonWriter.close(); 
            fw.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
```

I hope you can help me to solve my problem.
Thanks to everyone!

EDIT:

Now I have seen that this structure in my file doesn't solve my problem.
I want to splitt several JSON Strings which are saved in this txt file and my code only converts the first JSON String in a JSON Object. Here my code:

```
    try {
       FileReader fr = new FileReader("SelectedChoice.txt");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

       String zeile ="";

       while((zeile = br.readLine())!=null) {
           System.out.println(zeile);
           JSONObject choice = new JSONObject(zeile);
           System.out.println(choice);
       }

       br.close();
       fr.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I hope you can help me again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pretty print option:

```
   JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder(); 
   builder.add("Item", item); 
   builder.add("Choice 1", idchoice1); 
   builder.add("Choice 2", idchoice2);
   builder.add("Choice 3", idchoice3);
   JsonObject jo = builder.build();
   try { 
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>(1);
        properties.put(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, true);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("SelectedChoice.txt", true);
        JsonWriterFactory writerFactory = Json.createWriterFactory(properties);
        JsonWriter jsonWriter = writerFactory.createWriter(fw);
        jsonWriter.writeObject(jo);
        jsonWriter.close(); 
        fw.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```